# including a class template within a map

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class Test, and I am trying to define the following function in a separate header file:

```
template<typename T>
T dtest(const int, std::map<int, Test<T> >& y);
```

but I get the following error:

> ‘Test’ was not declared in this scope
>
> template argument 2 is invalid
>
> template argument 4 is invalid

Comment: Is the header if `Test`'s _definition_ included? Is it in the same namespace?

Comment: yes indeed, it is included...

Comment: Can you post the declaration of Test?

Comment: @Tomalak: What is your comment based on? What if Test.h is included but it defines name Test inside a namespace? itcpll would be right in saying "yes, its included" and still get the error he's getting.

Comment: @thekashyap: Kiril asked about that, and the answer was "yes". Which must be false.

Comment: "must be false" is your logic?! :))

Comment: @thekashyap is correct, I think I got myself into a circular include as Mark has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you assert that the header that defines `Test<T>` is included by the header that declares `dtest`, I'm going to guess you have a circular include: The `Test<T>` header also includes the `dtest` header.

Comment: declarations without definitions, and make sure to only pass one or the other type by pointer/reference, but not by value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
template<class T>
class Test{};

template<typename T>
T dtest(const int, std::map<int, Test<T> >& y);
```

This compiles fine so as long as you include the definition of Test and map; the code is fine.